# Objects are Not Valid as React Child when using Map Function to write React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, map-function

I am building a react native app which has a map function to create markers on a map for an array of different places. To do this I am using an API to get the coordinates and so need to use an async function as so:

```
<MapView style={styles.mapStyle}>
  {this.state.isLoading ? null : 
    this.state.places.map(async (place) => {
      const coords = await fetchCoords(place)

      return (
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate = {coords}
        />
      )
    })
  }
</MapView>
```

But this code gives the error: `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72})`. I am guessing the error is because I have implemented the async map function wrong. What should it be?

Comment: Did you console your coords variable? Is it returning your required values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate prop being passed to the Market component needs to be an object or array (representing latitude/longitude, x/y, etc) however what's being passed there is a promise.

The "const coords = await fetchCoords(place)" part should not take place directly with your render method, but instead somewhere else like componentDidMount then save to state, or make the async call in a higher order component and pass down the result as props. That will ensure the fetchCoords function doesn't unnecessarily get called on every re-render.